# Office 365 - Excel Advanced Filter - Mass Multiple Entries

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I've got over 16 000 line entries (stock). Out of the 16 000 I only want to filter 320 of the multiple stock codes in the "ITEM_CODE" column. Instead of selecting one at a time going through that huge list using the drop down filter, I want to select all at once (multiple stock codes). They do run in sequence i.e. row 620 to row 940. I only want to select that specific codes as I need to run a formula for those ones only. PS. I have never used or studied VBA to help me out so I have to do it with formulas etc. if possible.

Comment: Could you share some sample data with us along with the field name on which you want to filter records, will help  us to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could say

```
  if(and(row()<x,row()>y),formula, 0)
```

If you want to be able to sort the list (I will assume it's an Excel table, not a standard range), start by creating a list of the items codes you want to calculate the formula on...

Then add a formula like

```
   If(iserror(match(@[item_code],{created list},0)),0, formula)
```

If it's just filtering the list you are after, and it is all sorted, you could select the lot using Ctrl + g; a640:a480.

Then copy those cells to a new location, and use a slight variation on the second formula.

Answer (score 0):

I usually solve these type of problems by adding another column in the table.

In this column I add an if that will be true on the rows that I need.
Example if the number you are looking for is between 100 and 200 then use:

```
=IF(AND(A2>99,A2<201),"true","false")
```

Change "A" to the column you want to filter on. I assume your table starts at row 2.
And just fill down the column.
Then you can filter on this new column.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way to filter for a contiguous range of values is to select them, change their fill colour and then filter by colour.

A quick way to do this would be, for your example:

- Select the `ITEM_CODE` cell of row `620`
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Dn</kbd> multiple times and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and/or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> until the range down to row `940` is selected
- Change the fill colour of the selection
- Filter for that colour

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]